# to extract information from <a> in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to scrape the product url from the site "http://www.firstcry.com/teethers-and-soothers/5/98?ref2=menu_dd" from the below  tag:

```
     <a href="http://www.firstcry.com/nuby/nuby-orthodontic-pacifier/140905/product-detail" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_productdisplay_gvProductListDetails_ctl01_lnk_Image" onclick="jmp(this)">
                                <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_productdisplay_gvProductListDetails_ctl01_Img_view" title="Nuby - Orthodontic Pacifier" class="resizeimg" src="http://cdn.firstcry.com/brainbees/images/products/bigthumb/140905a.jpg" alt="Nuby - Orthodontic Pacifier" style="border-width:0px;border: none;vertical-align: middle;" original="http://cdn.firstcry.com/brainbees/images/products/bigthumb/140905a.jpg">

                                    </a>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
     return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a)'), function(link) {
        return link.getAttribute('href');
    });
```

Since this  element has no classname, and also the id is different for all the products, I don't know how to do this. I also don't know to use x-path in phantom if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Even if anchor has no classname and unique id, there is a pattern in the href: `{site}/{brand}/{productname}/{productid}/product-detail`.

Especially, the constant **product-detail** will help us to select products urls.

On the other part, to select -serialize- elements in the context of the web page, you shoudl use [page.evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html).

Here is a possible script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.firstcry.com/teethers-and-soothers/5/98?ref2=menu_dd';

page.open(url, function(status) {
    // list all the a.href links
    var alllinks = page.evaluate(function() {
        return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(link) {
            return link.getAttribute('href');
        }).filter(function(link) {return (link?link:'').indexOf('product-detail')>-1;});
    });

    console.log(alllinks.join('\n'));
    phantom.exit();
});
```